# Unable to use certain functions with LINQ to Entities?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to implement a search feature on a project using LINQ queries. Because the data sometimes contains characters with accents and other symbols, I created a method to remove these for the search.

Here is my code:

```
var addresses = (from a in db.Addresses
                 join b in db.Addresses on a.ClientID equals b.ClientID
                 where a.AddressType == 1 && b.AddressType == 2
                 select new
                 {
                     /* Columns selected */
                 });
var q = (from e in db.Employers
         join a in addresses on e.EmployerID equals a.id
         join i in db.IndustrialSectors on e.IndustrialSector equals i.ID
         select new
         {
             /* Columns selected */
         });

if (search != "")
{
    q = (from i in q
         where (
           Util.StringUtil.RemoveDiacritics(i.entity.ToString().ToLowerInvariant()).Contains(search) ||
           Util.StringUtil.RemoveDiacritics(i.name.ToString().ToLowerInvariant()).Contains(search)
         )
         select i);
}
```

It generates an exception saying that LINQ to Entities does not recognize my method (RemoveDiacritics(String)).

Comment: LINQ to entity will try to convert your LINQ expression to SQL or underlying data source language. Since there is no representation for your *particular* method it throws the exception.

Comment: If your underlying data source language is SQL you can use the static methods in the [SqlFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class in Entity Framework Linq queries

Comment: Which dialect of SQL are you coding against? If it is MS SQL Server could you implement the `RemoveDiacritics` function as a custom function, either in T-SQL or as a CLR-based function?

Answer (score 6):

When you use LINQ-to-Entities your LINQ query needs to be translated into a "server-side expression", which in English means something that the database can execute. The database doesn't know anything about your C# method called `RemoveDiacritics` so you get an error at run-time.

You will need to execute the query first and then use LINQ-to-Objects to do the filtering. That can be done simply by adding a `ToList()` to the query prior to filtering it. I'm a little more familiar with the fluent syntax, so I'd write it as:

```
q.ToList().Where(i =>
    Util.StringUtil.RemoveDiacritics(i.entity.ToString().ToLowerInvariant()).Contains(search) ||
    Util.StringUtil.RemoveDiacritics(i.name.ToString().ToLowerInvariant()).Contains(search));
```

You'll have to mess with it if you want the query syntax. It might be something like the following but I'm not 100% sure.

```
(from i in q.ToList()
 where Util.StringUtil.RemoveDiacritics(i.entity.ToString().ToLowerInvariant()).Contains(search) ||
       Util.StringUtil.RemoveDiacritics(i.name.ToString().ToLowerInvariant()).Contains(search));
```

Be aware, however, that this will bring back *everything* from the server and then perform the filtering client-side which may cause performance problems in your system depending on how much information is contained in your tables.

Comment: You don't want the bracket after "q": `(from i in q).ToList()` should be `(from i in q.ToList()`.

Comment: I tried to do this before on the queries before the if block, but I get an error that it can't implicitly convert from IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1> to IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>. I think it has something to do with the fact that I join both queries before the search, since I have been able to do it without that.

Comment: @Steven Rands: Corrected. Like I said, I don't use that syntax much.

Comment: @MGKarlo, have you tried what I suggested or just tried something like it elsewhere? There shouldn't be any different in results between `q.ToList().Where()` and `q.Where().ToList()`.

Comment: I managed to work around it by using ToList().Select(o => new { /* columns */}); back in the first query along with merging both queries into one. I'm still thinking there has to be a better way to accomplish this though.